# How to convert all int convertible data to int in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, int

I have pandas DF which has several `int type` data as strings and floats.
I would like to convert all the data that can be converted to `int` as `int` else leave it as it is.

```
# something like
df = df.applymap(lambda x: int(x) if type(int(x)) is int else x)

# this code is wrong and is something like x/y problem. But, is there a easy way workout this problem.
```

Thanks,

Comment: You can't have hetergenous types in pandas columns, unless you use `object` dtype. Which is not a good thing.

Answer (score -1):

You can use isdigit()

```
df.applymap(lambda x: 'int' if str(x).isdigit() else x)
```

Comment: Problematic: `'-10'`, `'0x1234'`, `'1e10'`